# SSP1117-5.0V Fin connected?

Tags: voltage-regulator, pins, pinout

I'm looking into the SSP1117-5.0V voltage regulator, but can't find if Fin is connected to any other pin.

Answer (score 2):

In general the tab would be connected to the middle pin. So no, there is no reason to think the tab is GND. The tab is Vout, like on many other 1117 type regulators.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, do you have a source I can add for the connection between the fin and Vout?

Comment: Almost all from the ten first datasheet PDFs of various 1117 regulators do mention this if you just put "1117 regulator tab" into your favourite search engine. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

I am 99.99% sure that it's connected to Vout, like every other xxx1117 regulator out there.

You should connect the tab to a large area of copper if the regulator is to dissipate much heat, since the die is mounted on the leadframe in such a way as to allow most of the heat to be conducted out through the tab. Image of *typical* SOT-223 package from [this](https://www.richtek.com/Design%20Support/Technical%20Document/AN044) website:

[image]

If you're seriously concerned you can either test one with an ohmmeter or contact the manufacturer http://www.siproin.com/en/Contact/ and ask them.

Answer (score 0):

[This datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1809201851_Shanghai-Siproin-Microelectronics-SSP1117-5-0V_C277893.pdf) seems to indicate that the fin isn't connected to anything in particular.  The safest thing to do would keep it electrically isolated.  You could also use an ohmmeter to see if it's connected to another pin, but that doesn't guarantee it's not connected to an internal node.

Comment: It does not indicate it's connected but it does not indicate isolation either. If it is isolated it means there are many designs/footprints that are not compatible with this regulator if the tab is isolated or connected to anything else than middle pin.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, sadly I have to make sure how this chip is built before I order.

Comment: If you must know, then ask the manufacturer or buy few as a sample. The thing is, if your design needs a rare exceptional 1117 with a floating tab, you will have hard time finding one, and if you do, you can't replace it easily if you want. It would just be better to make the design accept any standard 1117 regulator with the assumption that tab could be Vout or anything.